# Java - recursive generic type definitions

Tags: java, generics, interface

I tried to create an interface `ISortableStack` using `<E extends comparable <E>>` but I can't move forward. What does the following do?

```
<E extends Comparable<E>>
```

I've tried [this](http://www.cogs.susx.ac.uk/courses/dats/notes/html/node180.html), but it doesn't help.

Comment: What is your error, specifically?

Comment: There is no error , I just want to know how to create an interface with generic programming

Comment: Next time, please format your question correctly, and use the preview to check everything is OK before submitting.

Comment: Read the Java tutorial about generics. Without a more concrete question, we won't be able to give you a more concrete answer. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: This question is not really about stacks. What title could we use?

Comment: @Asphalt So you want a create a generic interface. What's the problem with it? Why can't you do it? Please, try to explain your problem.

Comment: for best results, you should use `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<E extends Comparable<E>>` means that `E` must be a type that knows how to compare to **itself**, hence, the recursive type definition.

```
public class Comparables {

  static class User implements Comparable<User> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(User user) {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  /**
   * This class cannot be used with Collections.sort because an
   * UncomparableUser is not comparable with itself. However, notice
   * that you get no compiler error just for implementing
   * Comparable<String>.
   */
  static class UncomparableUser implements Comparable<String> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(String user) {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<User> users = Arrays.asList(new User());

    // Using this would cause a compiler error
    // List<UncomparableUser> users = Arrays.asList(new UncomparableUser());

    Collections.sort(users);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking what does this mean:

```
<E extends Comparable<E>>
```

It means that the class 'E' passed in must implement the `Comparable` interface.

Comment: It's more than that. The class 'E' passed in must implement the Comparable interface, and the generic parameter of Comparable must be E itself.

Answer (score 1):

The `<` and `>` characters are part of the "generic" syntax. The standard library is choke full of "generic" interfaces; take a look at the `Set` [interface](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/Collections-Jar-Zip-Logging-regex/java/util/Set.java.htm) for an example.