# What does <R extends TableRecord<R>> mean in Java?

Tags: java, jooq

I'm creating an interface of JOOQ [TableRecord](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/2.2.x/org/jooq/class-use/TableRecord.html)

```
<R extends TableRecord<R>>
```

Would anyone be able to explain the line above?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7131714/521799, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1563335/521799, http://stackoverflow.com/q/695298/521799

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means a class of type R, that implements the interface `TableRecord<R>`

`TableRecord<R>` means that the interface is bound to the same type R.

An example would be a class like:

```
public class Bla implements TableRecord<Bla>
```

I admit this seems a bit strange, but Java generics don't really differentiate between `extends` and `implements`, which leads to some confusion.

As to why this exact definition, I don't know enough about the context to see exactly why it makes sense, but it might be due to method signatures on the interface returning objects of type `R` (think Factory):

```
public R createTableRecord(...);
```

Comment: But in this '<R extends TableRecord<R>> ' it extends it mean 'R' is a class?

Comment: I don't think R has to be the same type as the implementing class ([more reading)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553621/how-can-i-make-an-interface-instance-method-accept-arguments-of-the-same-class-o/18554262#18554262).

Comment: @subodh It means R is a "type", since TableRecord is an interface, R could be an interface as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
class SomeClass<R extends TableRecord<R>>
```

What it means that parameter type `R` has to be a subclass of `TableRecord <R>` and nothing else, i.e. you must use class

```
class Foo extends TableRecord <Foo>
```

as the parameter for defining your class `SomeClass`